# What are the item rarity colors in Xenoblade Chronicles 2?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

I’ve noticed that items I get from salvaging in Xenoblade Chronicles 2 come in a few different colors. (White, orange, purple). I assume these represent item rarity, but I’m not sure what each color means.

What are the item rarity colors in Xenoblade Chronicles 2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The item rarity colours, when on the ground, is as follows.

- White = Common
- Purple = Uncommon
- Orange = Rare

---

Likewise chests have a visual rarity to them, most notably when salvaging since chest in the field are not random.

- Brown chest = Common
- Red chest = Uncommon
- White chest = Rare