# What do the different collection point colors mean?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2, xenoblade-2-torna-golden-country

In *Xenoblade Chronicles 2: Torna ~ The Golden Country*, some collection points are colored orange instead of blue. What's the difference between orange and blue collection points? Are there other collection point colors?

[image: An orange collection point]

Answer (score 1):

Per the [wiki](https://xenoblade.fandom.com/wiki/Collection_Point), the color of the text indicates the rarity of items you can receive from the collection point

> [Collection points] are also colored differently depending on the rarity of their collectibles, with golden colored spots usually providing items of higher grade.

The wiki doesn't specify color rating other than gold (or yellow depending on screen resolution), but I'm guessing they are more-or-less the same as the [color rating](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/325787/124566) in the base game

Answer (score 0):

There are at least three different colors of collection points: Blue, Purple, and Gold. Based on [Wondercricket's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/398746/181240) and my own observations:

- Blue - Common collection points. Also used for old machines if you have a Silver Seeker
- Gold - Have a higher chance of dropping rare items. Also used for large old machines if you have a Golden Seeker.
- Purple - Can be a miasma residue spot that appears after dispersing an ether miasma, a Key Item spot like [Panacellin](https://xenoblade.fandom.com/wiki/Panacellin), or a gleaming rock

[image]